# Optimizing a function given its computed partial derivatives

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to optimize a function (find it's minimum). The function is parameterized with a vector `w`. So what I do basically is I computed the partial derivative of the function with respect to each parameter. Then I simply use gradient descent for this. However as far as I know, one can use more sophisticated optimization methods than gradient descent that don't need parameters to tune or care about. I would like to try one of those methods in `numpy` or `scipy` but I'm not able to figure out how. What I need is a method that accepts the computed partial derivatives values as input and then it optimizes the function. Does something like this exist in `numpy` or `scipy`?

Answer (score 3):

[`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) gives you an option to input the Jacobian and Hessian of the objective function:

`jac : bool or callable, optional`

> Jacobian (gradient) of objective function. Only for CG, BFGS, Newton-CG, L-BFGS-B, TNC, SLSQP, dogleg, trust-ncg. If jac is a Boolean and is True, fun is assumed to return the gradient along with the objective function. If False, the gradient will be estimated numerically. jac can also be a callable returning the gradient of the objective. In this case, it must accept the same arguments as fun.
>   hess,

`hessp : callable, optional`

> Hessian (matrix of second-order derivatives) of objective function or Hessian of objective function times an arbitrary vector p. Only for Newton-CG, dogleg, trust-ncg. Only one of hessp or hess needs to be given. If hess is provided, then hessp will be ignored. If neither hess nor hessp is provided, then the Hessian product will be approximated using finite differences on jac. hessp must compute the Hessian times an arbitrary vector.

As mentioned by @ffriend in a comment, you can find some example with and without gradient [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html).

Comment: Some [examples](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html), both - with and without gradient.

Comment: @ffriend thanks! I've added that to the answer since it is quite a comprehensive tutorial.